# How to split python script in parts and to import the parts in a loop?

Tags: python, loops, import, include

First, sorry for my stupid title :) And here is my problem.. Actually it's not a problem. Everything works, but I want to have better structure...

I have a python script with a loop "looped" each second.
In the loop there are many many IFs. Is it possible to put each IF in a separate file and then to include it in the loop? So this way every time the loop is "looped", all the IFs will be passed, too..

There are too many conditions in my script and all of them are different generally from the otheres so I want to have some kind of folder with modules - mod_wheather.py, mod_sport.py, mod_horoscope.py, etc..

Thanks in advance. I hope I wrote everything understandable..

**EDIT:**
Here is a structural example of what I have now:

```
while True:
   if condition=='news':
      #do something

   if condition=='sport':
      #so something else

   time.sleep(1)
```

It will be good if I can have something like this:

```
while True:
   import mod_news
   import mod_sport

   time.sleep(1)
```

And these IFs from the first example to be separated in files mod_news.py, mod_sport.py...

Comment: Smells like something funky's going on... Could you add a relevant segment of your code to the post please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

perhaps you wonder how to work with your own modules in general.
make one file named 'weather.py' and have it contain the appropriate if-statements like:

```
""" weather.py - conditions to check """

def check_all(*args, **kwargs):
    """ check all conditions """
    if check_temperature(kwargs['temperature']):
        ... your code ...

def check_temperature(temp):
    -- perhaps some code including temp or whatever ...
    return temp > 40
```

same for sport.py, horoscope.py etc

then your main script would look like:

```
import time, weather, sport, horoscope
kwargs = {'temperature':30}
condition = 'weather'
while True:
    if condition == 'weather':
        weather.check_all(**kwargs)
    elif condition == 'sport':
        sport.check_all()
    elif condition == 'horoscope':
        horoscope.check_all()
    time.sleep(1)
```

edit: edited according to the edit in your question. Note that I suggest importing all modules only one time, at the beginning of the script, and using its functions. This is better than executing code by importing. But if you insist, you could use `reload(weather)`, which actually performs a reload including code execution. But I cannot stress too much that using functions of external modules is a better way to go!

Comment: Thank you! It works. I've used your first example. I just do `weather.check_all('sport')` and `sport.check_all('sport')` in the loop and it works great. I've putted the IFs in the external modules, so this way it's perfect. Thank you once again.

Comment: you talked about debugging; if you do not use a debugger as in Eclipse with Pydev for example, you can use 'import traceback' and put the while loop after a 'try' statement like 'try: ..while loop .. except: traceback.print_exc()'. P.s., if it works, I would be honored by you accepting my answer!

Comment: Of course I will accept your answer. I was just doing some additional tests :) Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 4):

Put them in functions in separate files and then Import them:

```
"""thing1.py
   A function to demonstrate
"""

def do_things(some_var):
    print("Doing things with %s" % (some_var))
```

``

```
"""thing2.py
   Demonstrates the same thing with a condition
"""

def do_things(some_var):
    if len(some_var) < 10:
        print("%s is < 10 characters long" % (some_var))
    else:
        print("too long")
```

``

```
"""main_program.py"""
import thing1, thing2

myvar = "cats"
thing1.do_things(myvar)
thing2.do_things(myvar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps all you need is to call functions in your loop; and have those functions in other modules, which you import as needed.

```
while true:
   if condition:
      from module_a import f
      f()
   if condition2
      from module_b import g
      g()
```

Though the above is legal Python, and so answers your question, you should in practice write all the imports at the top of your file.

Comment: Don't do imports in the middle of a function, always put them at the top. Every import statement will re-execute the imported file.

Comment: Maybe in my case this will be a good thing. I want to re-execute the imported file every time in the loop and to check the IF conditions inside...

Comment: @Niki Stefanov - Is there any reason you can't just call a function?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for some kind of PHP-like `include()` or C prepocessor `#include`. You would have a file such as the `included.py` below:

```
a = 2
print "ok"
```

and another file which has the following code:

```
for i in values:
    import included
```

and you want the result to be equivalent to

```
for i in values:
    a = 2
    print "ok"
```

Is it what you are looking for? If so... no, it is not possible. Once Python imports a module, the code of the module is executed and following imports of the same mode only retrieve the already imported instance of the module. The code of a module is not executed everytime it is imported.

I can invent some crazy ways of doing it (let us say, `file.read()` + `eval()`, or calling `reload()` in an imported module.) but it would be a bad idea anyway. I bet we can think of a better solution to your *real* problem :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for.. :( Thank you for your answer. As I wrote above everything works now, but I just want to split the long script in parts for easier debugging.. too bad

Comment: if this is what you are looking for, please see the edit to my answer including the reload statement

Answer (score 0):

You could import the needed modules if they're needed, for example:

```
if condition:
    import weather
    ... do something
```

However I'm not sure if that's what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

> *I have a python script with a loop "looped" each second. In the loop
>   there are many many IFs.*

Then you must optimize the repeatedly executed tests. Suppose there are 50 IFs blocks in your code and that in a turn of the for-loop, the N th condition is True: that means that the N-1 other conditions must be tested before the N th is tested and triggers the execution of the corresponding code.

It would be preferable to do so:

```
# to_include.py

def func_weather(*args,**kwargs):
    # code
    return "I'm the weather"

def func_horoscope(*args,**kwargs):
    # code
    return "Give me your birth'date"

def func_gastronomy(*args,**kwargs):
    # code
    return 'Miam crunch'

def func_sports(*args,**kwargs):
    # code
    return 'golf, swimming and canoeing in the resort station'



didi = {'weather':func_weather, 'horoscope':func_horoscope,
        'gastronomy':func_gastronomy, 'sports':func_sports}
```

and the main module:

```
# use_to_include.py

import to_include

x = 'sports'

y = to_include.didi[x]()
# instead of
# if  x =='weather'   : y = func_weather()
# elif x=='horoscope' : y = func_horoscope()
# elif x=='gastronomy': y = func_gastronomy()
# elif x=='sports'    : y = func_sports()

print y
```

result

```
golf, swimming and canoeing in the resort station
```